# parse nested json object golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I want to parse mentioned **json**.

> {"foo":
>         [{ "bar": 1, "baz": 2 },{ "bar": 4, "baz": 25 }], "more":
>   "text"}

using below struct to unmarshal

```
type FooStruct struct {
   Bar int `json:"bar"`
   Baz int `json:"baz"`
}

type  ResponseStruct struct {
    More string `json:"more"`
    Foo []FooStruct `json:"foo"`
}
var contentHtml ResponseStruct
err = json.Unmarshal(<byte_array>, &contentHtml)
fmt.Printf("%+v", contentHtml.FooStruct[0].Bar)
```

Comment: And what is the question? https://play.golang.org/p/-B3jNUqQHF

Answer (score 0):

Your code is corrent, except this line:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", contentHtml.FooStruct[0].Bar)
```

There is no fields `FooStruct` in `ResponseStruct` type. I think you need to use `Foo` instead.
Working example on the <kbd>[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oNQlktxYN6)</kbd>